# How do i change my text everytime when i click on the link in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create a text generator however when i click on the link it can only generate some sample text which is stored in array once. I have tried using more than one string but i cant get it to work. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
            <title>Text generate 2 - copy</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
            </head>
            <body>
            <a href="#" id="link">Generate</a>

            <h1 id="head"></h1>
            <p id="para"></p>


            <script src="js/script.js"></script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

JS:

```
            var heading = document.getElementById('head');
            var paragraph = document.getElementById('para');

            var head = ["Sample heading one"];
            var para = ["Sample paragraph one"];

            document.getElementById("link").onclick = function visible() {

            if (heading.style.display = "none") 
            {
            heading.style.display = "block";
            }

            else 
            {
            heading.style.display = "block";
            }

            if (paragraph.style.display = "none") 
            {
            paragraph.style.display = "block";
            }

            else 
            {
            paragraph.style.display = "block";
            }

            heading.innerHTML = head;
            paragraph.innerHTML = para;
            }
```

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/vupexutu/1/edit)

Comment: `paragraph.style.display = "none"` should be `paragraph.style.display == "none"` I guess.

Comment: Yes - you need `==`.  Not sure if I really understood what you want to achieve, but try [this](http://jsbin.com/vupexutu/2/edit).  That uses an array of two strings for each div and selects one from each randomly onclick

Comment: You're if/else are doing the same thing.. this is not making sense.. what EXACTLY are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: Thats great but i would like the output to be different each time, thanks for the help appreciate it.